# How can I show Q1 to quarter without year on r

Tags: r

I am studying R and the exercise needs that I create a column to **Quarter** where the data seem Q4.

I use zoo library and lubridate, but the result that I achieved was a year plus Q1.

I have a column InvoiceDate where I it has a complete datetime.

[image]

What I need:

The original table, more specifically column, has a date-time like this: 2010-12-01 08:26:00. The column name is InvoiceDate. I need to get this column and to create other columns with specific values, like a quarter, year, month, etc.

[image]

What I archieved:

[image]

How do I achieve my goal?

Comment: Please, provide some reproducible example. What does the original table looks like?

Comment: The original table, more specifically column, has a date-time like this: 2010-12-01 08:26:00. The table name is **Date**. I need to get this column and to create other columns with specific values, like a quarter, year, month, etc...

Comment: We don't really know what you did since the question did not include the code but if you were using `"yearqtr"` class then format the yearqtr object like this:  `format(as.yearqtr(as.Date("2010-12-01 08:26:00")), "Q%q")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the inbuilt functions to extract the information that you need.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(quarter = quarters(InvoiceDate), 
         Month = format(InvoiceDate, '%b'), 
         weekday = weekdays(InvoiceDate))
```

Comment: The only thing is that da weekday to be complete and I need to get only 3 digits of the days. Sun, Tue, etc...

Comment: Instead of `weekdays` use `format(InvoiceDate, '%a')`.